# On the commutativity of integral and limit

Tags: calculus, integration, limits, multivariable-calculus

Suppose that $h\in C^1(\mathbb{R})$

I try to prove that:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_{0}^{t}h(t,x)dx=h(t,t)+\int_{0}^{t}\frac{\partial h}{\partial t}(t,x)dx$$
However this depends on the fact that:
$$\lim_{\Delta t\to0} \dfrac{\int_{0}^{t}(h(t+\Delta t,x)-h(t,x))dx}{\Delta t}=\int_{0}^{t} {\lim_{\Delta t\to0}\dfrac{(h(t+\Delta t,x)-h(t,x))dx}{\Delta t}}$$
I wonder when does it hold?

Comment: $h\in C^1$, you mean? Perhaps use the mean value theorem and uniform continuity. This is a standard result you can find many places.

Comment: [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)

Comment: What you wrote is incorrect since $t$ also appears in the upper limit of integration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as @azif00 mentioned this is a specific case of the leibniz integral rule, which states that:
$$\frac d{dx}\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}f(x,t)\,dt=f(x,b(x))\frac{db(x)}{x}-f(x,a(x))\frac{da(x)}{dx}+\int_{a(x)}^{b(x)}\frac{\partial f(x,t)}{\partial x}\,dt$$
You could definitely derive a proof for this from first principles

---

In your case, we have:
$$\frac{d}{dt}\int_0^t h(t,x)\,dx=h(t,t)\frac{dt}{dt}-h(t,0)\frac{d0}{dt}+\int_0^t\frac{\partial h(t,x)}{\partial t}\,dx\\=h(t,t)+\int_0^t\frac{\partial h(t,x)}{\partial t}\,dx$$